# Perfect squares in a given range: abnormal execution of loops

Tags: c++, algorithm, loops

**Program number 1**:
In a given range *a* and *b* where *a*<=*b*, I want to find whether a number is a perfect quare, if yes then print its root. Therefore, I wrote the following code:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
float squaredroot(int n) {
float low = 0.0, mid;
float high = (float)n+1;
while ((high-low) > 0.00001) {
    mid = (low+high) / 2;
    if (mid*mid < n) {
        low = mid;
    }
    else {
        high = mid;
    }
}
return low;
}

int main() {
int a,b,i=0; cin>>a>>b;
float roo=0.0;
for(i=a;i<=b;i++){
roo=squaredroot(i);
    if(floor(roo)==roo){
        cout<<roo<<endl;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

For the given input `1 5` the output should be `2`. But, the above program is not printing any value.

---

Nevertheless, when I tried running another program using the same base concept as Program number 1, that's mentioned above, It was executed perfectly. 
The task for the following program is to check whether the input is a perfect square or not. If yes, then print the root of the number, else print "Not a perfect square!". Here is the code for the **Program number 2**:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
float squaredroot(int n) {
float low = 0.0, mid;
float high = (float)n+1;
while ((high-low) > 0.00001) {
    mid = (low+high) / 2;
    if (mid*mid < n) {
        low = mid;
    }
    else {
        high = mid;
    }
}
return low;
}

int main() {
int a; cin>>a;
float roo=0.0;
roo=squaredroot(a);
if(floor(roo)==roo){
    cout<<roo<<endl;
}
else{
    cout<<"Not a perfect square!"<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

I am unable to find the mistake in the first program. Please help.

Comment: If you are interested in integers, why do you use *float*? The type float is good enough for simple calculations where you can accept some rounding errors; but anywhere else it is nothing but trouble.

Comment: @Gyro Gearloose There may be many possible ways to solve the above problem. But the main intention of asking this question is to know why the _for_ and/or _if_ loop in **Program 1** is behaving abnormally. P.S. Changed the question title accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of messing about with the square root function, consider this:

- Consecutive squares are separated by succeeding odd numbers.
- It's pretty darned fast to add some integers. Also you are skipping more and more numbers each time.
- Square root takes you to floats. This keeps the problem in integers, where it belongs.

So, to solve your problem elegantly, just do this:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

void print_perfect_square( int start, int end ) {
    int x = 0, nthOdd = 1;

    while ( x <= end ) {
        if ( x >= start ) {
            cout << x << " is a square and its root is "
                << nthOdd - 1  << '\n';
        }
        x += 2*nthOdd - 1;
        ++nthOdd;
    }
}

int main() {
    // it should find 9 and 16
    print_perfect_square(6,17);
    cout << '\n';
    // it sholuld skip negatives
    print_perfect_square(-10,5);
    cout << '\n';
    // it should print 25,36...
    print_perfect_square(20,100);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly well. Still, the question is what is wrong with **Program 1**. The error must be in the _for_ loop.

Comment: @RaviKiran if the square root returned is not quite exact, the floor function will be different to the square root, causing you to miss that output incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

As Gyro Gearloose said, the problem is that `squaredroot(4)` returns `1.99999809`, so `floor(roo)!=roo`. One way to fix this is to change the condition `(floor(roo)==roo)` to `(fabs(roo - floor(roo+0.5)) < 0.00001)`. Notice that I'm using the same `0.00001` from the function `squaredroot`.

Comment: Typo: you mean `squaredroot(4)`

Comment: For the same input, as mentioned in the question, the output of the **Program1** after the suggested modification is `0.999992` `2`. The desired output is 2(should be an integer).
Still, the question is, if **Program 2** was able to print `2` for `squaredroot(4)` then why **program 1** is failing to do so.

Comment: To fix the output, print `floor(roo+0.5)` instead of printing `roo`. As for program 2, on my machine it doesn't work well either.